# Relationship between the Pfaffian and determinant from exterior algebra

Tags: determinant, multilinear-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices, pfaffian

I have been trying to prove the well-known relation linking the Pfaffian and the determinant from their definitions in terms of the exterior algebra, but unfortunately I haven't been able to work it out myself, nor to find the proof elsewhere.

Here go the definitions:

Let $E$ be an even dimensional vector space ($dimE=2n$) equipped with a Euclidean metric $g$. Let $f:E \rightarrow E$ be an antisymmetric endomorphism. Then $f$ induces a form $\omega \in \bigwedge^2 E$ given by $\omega(w, v)=g(f(w), v)$. This is equivalent to defining $\omega = \sum_{i<j}a_{ij} e_i\wedge e_j $, where $(a_{ij})$ is the matrix of $f$ with respect to an orthonormal basis of $E$.

Now, if we take $\omega^n$ -this means $\omega \wedge \omega ...$, $n$ times-, we realise $\omega^n \in \bigwedge^{2n} E$, which is one-dimensional, so that we must have:

$$ \omega^n= Pe_1\wedge e_2 \wedge ... \wedge e_{2n} $$ This constant $P$ is called the Pfaffian.

As for the determinant, we know that $f$ induces an $\bigwedge^{2n} f: \bigwedge^{2n} E \rightarrow \bigwedge^{2n} E$. Now, linear endomorphisms of one-dimensional vector spaces are just multiplication by a scalar. In our case, we define:

$$(\bigwedge^{2n} f) (e_1\wedge e_2 \wedge ... \wedge e_{2n})=det(f)e_1\wedge e_2 \wedge ... \wedge e_{2n}$$.

From this definitions one should be able to derive the well-known formula:

$$Pf(f)^2=det(f)$$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean $Pf(f^2)$?

Comment: The square of the Pfaffian equals the determinant

Comment: I don't see how to get around *some* of the standard arguments (seeing what happens for orthogonal $2\times 2$ blocks). I do believe, however, that you have some constants flying around in your formula.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't undertand, you think some of my formulation is wrong? I haven't been able to find any proof from those definitions.

Comment: I think maybe I can start with the diagonalisation of a skew-symmetric matrix and then use the intrinsic definition of \omega? I believe I would need to extend the scalar product to complex vectors then... I think that might be a step in the right direction but I'm not sure how to work out the details.